# Anchor tag is not working Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, anchor

i am beginner in field of chrome extension. currently i am making an extension in which i want to open a new page in extension tab on a single click. so this is my code for popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Open Google</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>     
</body>
</html>
```

google link is working when i opened it as a html page but this is not working in my extension. 
this is my manifest.json file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Open Google",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab"
]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Might this helps you!

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer though one thing worth mentioning for anyone that might find it helpful is that links in a Firefox extension don't require this attribute and work just fine without it!

Comment: `rel="noopener noreferrer"` should be added to avoid vulnerability.